# Qt Creator environment variables for project settings

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to use environment variables for the project settings in Qt Creator 4.0.3?

[image: image: project settings]

The variable is called `BUILD_FOLDER` and I tried to use it with `%{BUILD_FOLDER}` and with `$$(BUILD_FOLDER)`.

How can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the %{...}-substitution that works in many places in creator.

%{Env:PATH} can be used to access the current environment and there are many more things you can expand. Click on the AZ icon in the line to get a list of supported substitutions.

You can you a lot with these substitutions: E.g. %{Js: ...} will evaluate javascript expressions (which may *not* contain { or } themselves!) and also makes a lot of the kit settings available to be passed to scripts or to be used in the project environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#using-environment-variables), it should be possible. You just have to use the platform native syntax, ie. `$VARIABLE` on Linux and `%VARIABLE%` on Windows.

> **Using Environment Variables**
>
> You can use any environment variables as values in the fields. For a list of variable names, click Build Environment Details in the Build Settings. Environment variables are referenced using the native syntax: $VARNAME or ${VARNAME} on Unix and %VARNAME% on Windows.